# What's wrong with me PHP code to get form values into text file?

Tags: php, html, forms

Here's the form:

```
<form>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message" 
placeholder="Grateful for?">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type=submit value="&#10086;">
    <input type="reset" value="&#x2716;">
</form>
```

Here's the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$Message = $_POST['message'];
$file = fopen("post.txt", "a");
fwrite($file, $Name, $Message);

fclose($file);

}
?>
```

Form is asking for input of a 'name' and a short 'message', those values should be available with PHP $_POST superglobal. Is my syntax correct with the "$Name" or "Message" variable associated with the $_POST variable?

The $file variable looks correctly set to my post.txt and am I writing out correct syntax for fwrite and fclose?

Comment: What is `<form>
    <form ...`???

Comment: The <form> tag? What are you asking?

Comment: The two form tags?

Comment: Ya <form> to open the form and </form> to close it.

Comment: No. Your first two tags are both form tags.

Comment: Oh! ya ur right, the form action I thought was one tag

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive `$_POST['submit']`, you need to have a field with `name="submit"`.

You can set that name to your submit button:

```html
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="&#10086;">
```

Also, keep in mind that `fwrite()` has the following signature:

```
fwrite ( resource $handle , string $string [, int $length ] ) : int
```

You can simplify your code with `file_put_contents()` though:

```php
file_put_contents('post.txt', "$Name\n$Message\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

I'm assuming you want to have your name and message separated by new line character in the file and you want to append to the file.

Comment: Right, even trickier get name bold and message regular

Comment: Do you store multiple posts in that file or just one?

Comment: Every post yes in that one file

Comment: Then appending looks like a good idea, as saving will be fast. But keep in mind that if someone puts a new line character to the message, it can get tricky (or impossible) to retrieve data, because you no longer know where each post ends in the file.

Comment: Ya I've also got the option for every post to have its own file. I also want a css line border and faint grey fill to differentiate posts.

Comment: The styling is another topic. You need to start from storing data somehow. Have you considered database?

Comment: Ya MySQL to store my login user and passwords, I guess posts could be there too.

Comment: I encourage you to use database for storing posts for sure. It will be much easier in the long run to maintain your posts in the database.

Comment: My host says: 
    Database Space Limit: 1GB
    Database Table Limit: 100 Tables
    Manage your database at databases.000webhost.com
    Use localhost as a connection hostname.

does 100 tables mean theoretically only 100 posts? Or do you think that means 100 databases?

Comment: These limits are perfectly fine. 1 GB is quite a lot of data and 100 tables is more than enough for most projects.

Comment: So by 100 tables they mean I can make 100 database files? just want to be sure.